# How do I change Object Property Names when you 'print' to the screen

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, properties

I have an Array of objects.

```
allInfo= [{
   firstName: test1,
   middleName: test2,
   lastName:test3,
}
{
firstName: testA,
   middleName: testB,
   lastName:testC,
}];
```

How do I change the 'firstName' to 'First Name' when I output it to the HTML DOM?

The current output is this:

```
firstName: Jeff - middleName: Michael - lastName: Ward
```

And I want it to be:

```
First Name: Jeff - Middle Name: Michael - Last Name: Ward
```

I have tried to use an If/Else Statement, and that did not work.  I am sure there is some simple fix for this.  Can Anyone lend a hand?  Thanks!

My code:

```
function generate(list) {
  var out = '<ul>';

  for (var i in list) {
    var rec = list[i];

    var row = [];
    for (var field in rec) {
        if(field === firstName){ field = "First Name";}
    else if{field === middleName){ field = "Middle Name";}
    else if{field === lastName){ field = "Last Name";}

      row.push(field + ': ' + rec[field]);
    }

    out += "<li>" + row.join('  -  ') + "</li>";
  }

  out += "</ul>"
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = out;
  return out;
}
```

My whole JS file:

```
var allInfo = []; //Store names (as objects) here
var output = printList('output');
var cache = [];
var numOfNames = 0;
var nameCounter = 0

alert("JS Works");


function buildList() { //Makes a new object, and pushes it to the 'allInfo' Array
  var info = {};
  info.firstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
  info.middleName = document.getElementById('middleName').value;
  info.lastName = document.getElementById('lastName').value;
  allInfo.push(info);
  addName(1);
  clear();
  alert("Logged");

}


function resetList() {
  allInfo = [];
  numOfNames = 0;
  nameCounter = 0;
  addName(0);
  blankOut();
}

function blankOut() {
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = " ";
}

//Problem Function
function generate(list) {
  var out = '<ul>';

  for (var i in list) {
    var rec = list[i];

    var row = [];
    for (var field in rec) {
      row.push(field + ': ' + rec[field]);
    }

    out += "<li>" + row.join('  -  ') + "</li>";
  }

  out += "</ul>"
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = out;
  return out;
}


function addName(x) {
  if (x > 0) {
    nameCounter++;
    numOfNames = nameCounter;
    document.getElementById('numOfNames').innerHTML = numOfNames;
  } else {
    nameCounter = 0;
    numOfNames = 0;
    document.getElementById('numOfNames').innerHTML = numOfNames;
  }
}

function printList(x) {
  var output = getById(x);
  return function (text) {
    output.innerHTML += text + '\n';
  };
}


function getById(x) {
  return document.getElementById(x);
}


function clear() {
  document.getElementById("firstName").value = "";
  document.getElementById("middleName").value = "";
  document.getElementById("lastName").value = "";
}
```

Comment: `if (field === firstName)` doesn't look right. Keys are strings, but you are comparing to an identifier, that doesn't exist.

Comment: I tried to do if (field === ['firstName'])  and that didn't work either.

Comment: That compares a string to an array... You want to compare a string to a string. Also, you seem to have a few syntax errors.

Comment: I thought I was comparing the 'field' (which is the property name) to a value, and if it matched, I would substitue field for "First Name".

Comment: What @elcanrs said is if (field === 'firstName') not if (field === ['firstName'])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code segment:

```
for (var field in rec) {
  if(field === firstName){ field = "First Name";}
  else if{field === middleName){ field = "Middle Name";}
  else if{field === lastName){ field = "Last Name";}

  row.push(field + ': ' + rec[field]);
}
```

You should be comparing the object key (field) to a String representation, like so:

```
for (var field in rec) {
  var fieldLabel;

  if (field === 'firstName') { fieldLabel = "First Name"; }
  else if (field === 'middleName') { fieldLabel = "Middle Name"; }
  else if (field === 'lastName') { fieldLabel = "Last Name"; }

  row.push(fieldLabel + ': ' + rec[field]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an object to map the field name to a label, like so:

```
var labels = { "firstName": "First Name", "middleName": "Middle Name", "lastName": "Last Name"};
var field;

for (field in rec) {
  row.push(labels[field] + ': ' + rec[field]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `toUpperCase` to capitalize the first character, and use the regex `[A-Z]` to insert a space before every capital letter.

```js
str[0].toUpperCase() + str.substr(1).replace(/[A-Z]/g, ' $&')
```